# Multiple values in SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select

How could i formulate a SELECT query where the values of one of the fields is dynamic, specfically, the values of **sintom**, which is an array of String,are determined upon execution how could I modify this query:

```
       q = "SELECT DISTINCT nome FROM malattia WHERE eta='" + age + "' AND sesso='" + sexstr + "' AND etnia='" + etniastr + "' AND sintomi IN('" + sexstr + "')";
```

I would need something like this:

```
  ... AND sintomi IN('" + sexstr[0] + "','" + sexstr[1] + "','" + sexstr[2] + "')";
```

The array **sintom** can have a length of 1 upto 10, I didn't opt for preparedstatement thought it would be abit simple, if i use concatenation of strings.More over i can't use a loop because i need to accomplish it in a single query. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Joiner.on("','").join(array)` or [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) `StringUtils.join(array, "','")`

Comment: I was thinking the other way is the always have 10 elements and populate the unused ones with junk that won't match, but this answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks and how should this change my query?

Comment: instead of having + ... + ... , you just put the `join(..)` within IN('" ... "')